# Array dynamic input of values

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

So basically I want to have my output like this:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtjvZ.png)

The quantity of questions is based on how many questions the user adds and is stored in an `ArrayList`. The choices are also dynamically inputted and stored in an array.

The problem is this is what happens:

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPhiq.png)

It displayed in question 1 the choices I entered for question 2 instead of displaying it's own set of choices.

So this is the code for start game:

```
public static void startGame(){
    int correctAnswers = 0; //used for later
    int count = 1, counter, 
    System.out.println("===Have fun===");
    for(Question question: myQuestions){
        System.out.println("Question " +count);
        System.out.println(question.getQuestions());
        count++;
        counter=1;
        for(String i :question.getChoices()){
        System.out.printf("[%d]%s\n",counter,i);
        counter++;

        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for add question:

```
public static void addQuestion(){
    String[]choices = new String[3];
    String question = "";
    char yesorno;
    int answerIndex;

    System.out.println("==Add Question==");
    do{
    System.out.print("Enter question: ");
    try{
        question = console.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print("Enter choices <Fixed 3 choices> \n");
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        System.out.printf("[%d] ",i);
        choices[i] = scan.next();

    }

    System.out.print("Enter the choice of the right answer [0,1 or 2}: ");
    answerIndex = scan.nextInt();
    Question quest = new Question(choices,question,answerIndex);
    myQuestions.add(quest);
    System.out.print("Do you want to add more questions?<Y/N> ");
    yesorno = Character.toLowerCase(scan.next(".").charAt(0));

    }while(yesorno == 'y');
    start();
}
```

Considering these declarations(For information purposes only):

```
//declared in the main class.
static ArrayList<Question> myQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();
static BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//Question class
public class Question {
private String[]choices = new String[3];
private String questions;
private int answerIndex;

public Question(String[] choices, String questions, int answerIndex){
    this.choices = choices;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.answerIndex = answerIndex;
}
public String[] getChoices(){
    return choices;
}
public String getQuestions(){
    return questions;
}
public int getAnswerIndex(){
    return answerIndex;
}

}
```

Thanks guys in advance! :D

Comment: Did you have a look at the myQuestions variable after inserting the data?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Post your addQuestion method as the problem should be there

Comment: @k4yaman  experimented and I looked at it through a method and from there the choices for the second question are also recorded for the first question! It seems that my addQuestion records the last inputted choices and assigns them to all of the questions. :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating choices values which is referenced in each question object. Do a choices = new String[3] at the end of each loop iteration and it will work

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! 
As said by @Aitor I am updating my String[] choices in every iteration of my do-while loop in my addQuestion method. I just added choices = new String[3] in the last part of my do block and everything worked fine!

This is my updated addQuestion method:

```
public static void addQuestion(){
    String[]choices = new String[3];
    String question = "";
    char yesorno;
    int answerIndex;

    System.out.println("==Add Question==");
    do{
    System.out.print("Enter question: ");
    try{
        question = console.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print("Enter choices <Fixed 3 choices> \n");
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        System.out.printf("[%d] ",i);
        choices[i] = scan.next();   
    }

    System.out.print("Enter the choice of the right answer [0,1 or 2}: ");
    answerIndex = scan.nextInt();
    Question quest = new Question(choices,question,answerIndex);
    myQuestions.add(quest);
    System.out.print("Do you want to add more questions?<Y/N> ");
    yesorno = Character.toLowerCase(scan.next(".").charAt(0));
    choices = new String[3];//Solution. Thanks for this Aitor!
    }while(yesorno == 'y');
    start();
}
```

Much appreciated help. Stack Overflow (through our fellow programmers) never fails to help all of us. Much respect! :) 'til next time